# Validation on application execution using core_ and paper_elements

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer, material-design, paper-elements, core-elements

I noticed that with the release of paper_elements 0.1.0+2 and core_elements 0.1.1, validation is seen on a property as soon as the application is executed. This occurs even before the user interacts with the component.

Is there a way to override this?

I would like for the user to start interacting with the element before the validation begins. To place errors in an application even before the user starts to use the application does not seem self-intuitive to me.

An example provide by polymer can be seen at http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input

... the third paper_input element is the one being discussed. From the example above it seems as if the authors hook the error display to the error attribute. I am wondering why could it not be linked with a red asterisk at a specific site - such as after a label - that would not seem overly intrusive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported

```dart
<paper-input id="custom" on-input="{{inputHandler}}" validateImmediately="false"></paper-input>
<!-- default is "true" -->
```